# Adding two rows of cells to an Excel spreadsheet after a blank cell in column A

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working in a spreadsheet that has many, many rows of data, but that needs blank rows added per the instructions of someone of a higher pay grade than my own.

Essentially, I want to add two rows of blank cells beneath any row where there is no information in column A. 
I tried to write a module to do this, but I am clearly not knowledgeable enough to do so.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something that you'll have to do often, I'd write a macro (can't help you. Haven't done them in forever), but if this is just a one-off, I'd start by adding a column of indices to maintain ordering. Next to it, get a 1 into each row that you want to insert blank rows below. Suppose this is column B.

```
=IF($A1="",1,0)
```

In the next column (C) get the value to be the number of 1's so far. (set C1 by hand)

```
=IF($B2=0,$C1,$C1+1)
```

Now you need a column (D) that just has the count values where there's a blank row (0's otherwise):

```
=IF($B1=0,0,$C1)
```

Now sort your graph by the D column. This should end up with all of your blank entry rows at the bottom. Go to the end of them. See how many you have. Say you have 100. Now below them in the D column, give blank rows the numbers 1 to 100. Do it again below that. Now resort based on D. You should now have your A entry rows followed by your non-A entry rows, each of which has two blank rows below it. Now, add a new column (E) that checks your sorting index column (call it J). (set E1 and E2 by hand).

```
=IF($J3="",IF($J2="",$J1+0.1,$J2+0.1),$J3)
```

Now resort everything by column E and you should have exactly what you want in the original ordering (plus some extra columns that can now be discarded).